# Setting resource limits works for SSH logins but not local logins

Tags: ubuntu

I followed the instruction of the link below to set up the resource limits for myself only (in sudo list): https://mapr.com/docs/52/AdvancedInstallation/SettingResourceLimitsOnUbuntu.html

Basically, add resource limits for the user in /etc/security/limits.conf, and

Additionally, I edited three files - /etc/pam.d/common-session* and /etc/pam.d/su, and add the following line to the end: session required pam_limits.so

However, this works for all SSH logins, but not for local logins (console) after log back or reboot. I use ulimit commands to check the changes.

Need your suggestions for this.

Thanks.